# array of submit buttons in different forms generated with php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, submit

I dynamically create html forms with a loop in php and each submit button is assigned a name as part of an array. How can I check which submit button is set and get its value? I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
      if($count_eksp){for($i=0; $i<$count_eksp; $i++){
      $fusha_eksp = mysql_fetch_row($query1);

      echo "<br>$fusha_eksp[2] $fusha_eksp[3]<form method='post' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'><input name='eksp_edit[]' type='submit' value='$fusha_eksp[0]' height='20' width='20' ><input id='eksp_fshi[]' type='image' src='fshi.png' height='20' width='20'></form>";

     }}
  ?>
 <?php 
       if(isset($_POST['eksp_edit[]'])){

       foreach($_POST['eksp_edit'] as $id){
       $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `fusha_ekspertizes` WHERE `id`='$id'", $db_server);
       }


 }
?>
```

Comment: try to give different ids to form

Comment: give unique ids to forms and remove square brackets 
eksp_edit[] to eksp_edit

Answer (score 0):

You have error in `if` condition, in the key. Remove `[]` for that.

```
if (isset($_POST['eksp_edit'])) {
    ...  
}
```

The second error is in action attribute, you can have another `<?` inside `echo`. When the form is processed on the same page, you can leave this attribute.

```
echo "[...]<form method='post'><input [...]";
```